# Confusion about recursion in a BST python

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to understand the recursive call within the binary function `is_bst`. The goal of the function is to check if a tree is a binary search tree or not. Note, This is just an excerpt from the complete function. I am trying to understand what is happening on this block of code `is_bst_l, min_l, max_l = is_bst(node.left)` in the `is_bst` function. The `is_bst` function return `(True, None, None)`, I am trying to figure out how the function came up with the return value by going through the function recursively. The `is_bst` function takes as input the binary tree node from the  `parse_tuple` function. As an example, when I try to unpack this line of code `is_bst_l, min_l, max_l  = node.left` outside the `is_bst` function  I get `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable TreeNode object`, but within the function, I don't get an error. My Question is

1. what is happening recursively within the `is_bst` function.
2. How can I don't get the unpack TypeError within the `is_bst` function.

`
[image]

```
#Tree Class
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

#function converts a turble to a binary tree
 def parse_tuple(data):
    # print(data)
    if isinstance(data, tuple) and len(data) == 3:
        node = TreeNode(data[1])
        node.left = parse_tuple(data[0])
        node.right = parse_tuple(data[2])
    elif data is None:
        node = None
    else:
        node = TreeNode(data)
    return node
```

Function Checks if a tree is a Binary search tree or not.

```
def remove_none(nums):
return [x for x in nums if x is not None]

def is_bst(node):
    if node is None:
        return True, None, None
    
    is_bst_l, min_l, max_l = is_bst(node.left)
    is_bst_r, min_r, max_r = is_bst(node.right)
    is_bst_node = (is_bst_l and is_bst_r and 
              (max_l is None or node.key > max_l) and 
              (min_r is None or node.key < min_r))
#     print('Minkey left: ', min_l, 'Nodekey :', node.key, 'Maxkey left: ',min_r)
#     print('Minkey left: ', max_l, 'Nodekey :', node.key, 'Maxkey left: ',max_r)
    min_key = min(remove_none([min_l, node.key, min_r]))
    max_key = max(remove_none([max_l, node.key, max_r]))
    
    # print(node.key, min_key, max_key, is_bst_node)
        
    return is_bst_node, min_key, max_key
```

#function call

```
my_tuple= ((None,3,None),2,(None,5,None))
node = parse_tuple(my_tuple)
```

Comment: it is not checking if the tree isBST or not, you are just travsing

Comment: @sahasrara62 yeah I understand that, I just want to understand the recursive call within the function `is_bst`. Like I mentioned in the question the `is_bst` is just an excerpt  from the complete `is_bst` function.

Comment: where is complete `is_bst` function ? it is just pre order traversal

Comment: @sahasrara62 I have updated the question with the complete `is_bst` function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69881096/minimum-and-maximum-elements-of-a-binary-search-tree-python?noredirect=1#comment123527350_69881096

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69883804/how-to-remove-all-occurences-of-an-element-in-a-binary-search-tree-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is returning the maximum and minimum key on the left and right of the current node (in addition to the True/False result of the check). Its recursion assembles these keys / validity states from the left and right nodes creating the need to manage (i.e. exclude) None results from the subnodes returned value.

This is overly complex, and probably not worth your time to analyze and understand.

I think you'll find this one a bit more straightforward:

```
def is_bst(node,minKey=None,maxKey=None):
    if node is None: return True
    if minKey is not None and node.key<=minKey: return False
    if maxKey is not None and node.key>=maxKey: return False
    if not is_bst(node.left,minKey,self.key):   return False
    if not is_bst(node.right,self.key,maxKey):  return False
    return True
```

Comment: your solution does not return the minKey and maxKey

Comment: Why should it?  *"The goal of the function is to check if a tree is a binary search tree or not"*. In any implementation those two would be separate (and much simpler) functions. e.g. `def minKey(self): return self.left.minKey() if self.left else self.key`

Answer (score 1):

A tree is a BST if recursively for every node:

- Its left tree if it exists is a BST
- Its right tree if it exists is a BST
- The largest value of the left tree, if it exists, must be smaller than the node's value
- The smallest value of the right tree, if it exists, must be larger than the node's value

Hence it makes sense for the return value to the the tuple of three values:

- Am I a BST?
- What is the smallest node in my subtree
- What is the largest node in my subtree.

Comment: I jsut updated the question with complete function. The tree is not a BST, the smallest node is 2 and the largest node is 5. I just want to understand what is happening on the line of code `is_bst_l, min_l, max_l = is_bst(node.left)`.  forgive me if my question sounds absurd .

Comment: Exactly what I explained above.  The function `is_bst` returns three values: look at every `return` statement and you will see three values.  This line then causes those three returned values to be assigned to three variables.

Comment: I think I am begining to understand that now from your above explanation. thanks

Answer (score 0):

When **is_bst(node.left)** or  **is_bst(node.right)** returns **"None"** for max_l,_min_l or max_r,min_r the following hapens:

condition = (max_l is None) or (node.key > max_l)
condition1 : (max_l is None)
condition2 : (node.key >max_l)

**Case1:**
is_bst_l, min_l, max_l = is_bst(True,None,None)

condition = condition1 or condition2
condition = True or **condition2 will not be processed** since condition1 is "False"
condition = True because of condition1

**Case2:**
is_bst_l, min_l, max_l = is_bst(True,1,1)

condition = condition1 or condition2
condition = False or **condition2 will be processed** since condition1 is not "True"
condition = True because of condition2